# Когда выделяестя память для методов экземпляра класса: при его создании, или при обращении к данному методу?

Tags: python

Допустим, имеется класс, экземпляр которого должен иметь относительно немного атрибутов (переменных) и пару десятков методов на несколько десятков килобайт для работы с ними. И предполагается, что таких экземпляров (объектов) будет довольно много.
Первое, что приходит на ум, это то, что конструктор класса при создании каждого экземпляра выделит память для всех методов и будет хранить их код на протяжении жизни объекта.
Но логичнее было бы, если память под код конкретного метода выделялась бы в момент обращения к нему и освобождалась по окончании исполнения этого кода.
Если верно первое, то придется по возможности использовать статические методы вместо методов экземпляра, а если второе, то можно создавать методы экземпляра класса без ограничений.
Хочется узнать мнение экспертов об этом.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду именно **код** или **локальные переменные** метода? Код создается (и память под оттранслированный байт-код) один раз для всех экземпляров класса (даже если их вообще ни одного не будет). Память под локальные переменные метода  выделяется при каждом его вызове (и тоже не зависит от количества экземпляров). Вообще, было бы лучше, если бы вы сопроводили свой вопрос несколькими примерами кода и спрашивали уже про эти примеры

Comment: Я имею ввиду то, что каждый раз при применении метода экземпляра класса, вызывается  копия кода функции, а не общая для всех экземпляров класса статическая функция (что было бы странно) .  Вопрос в том, эта копия кода живёт столько же, сколько живёт данный объект, или создаëтся и удаляется динамически, по мере необходимости.

Comment: самое простое - имитировать ваше предположение (написать код класса, создать кучу объектов) и узнать истинно ваше предположение или нет. так быстрее выясните. забавно будет, если в питоне оно так.

Comment: Думаю, что можно обойтись парой экземпляров класса, распечатав указатели на методы до, после и в процессе выполнения, но до понедельника питона под рукой нет, поэтому и спрашиваю)))

Comment: Стоит разделять понятия **метод**, **функция** и **код функции**. Питон устроен настолько специфически, что можно создавать несколько разных функций, использующих один и тот же код. Метод — это вообще не функция, а хитрый объект-обёртка, который хранит в себе ссылки на собственно функцию и на экземпляр нужного объекта. Попробуйте сделать `print(MyClass.method)` — вы увидите `bound object`, который хранит функцию в атрибуте `__func__` и экземпляр в атрибуте `__self__`. Если вы сделаете print несколько раз, то увидите, что id меняется — этот bound method создаётся каждый раз заново на лету.

Comment: То что написано внутри `def` хранится в программе в единственном экземпляре. Даже если это `def` метода объекта и вы создали миллион экземпляров объекта. Экземпляров может быть много, замыканий - много, а определение функции - единственно.

Answer (score 1):

Если бы методы класса дублировались в каждом экземпляре, то для списка из 1000 000 `int`'ов было бы по 1 млн копий каждого метода положенного типу `int`, на деле же каждый экземпляр  имеет ссылку на тип/класс `int`, через которую получает доступ к общим методам.

В Python всё является объектом, в том числе создаваемые пользователем классы/типы и функции создаваемые с помощью `def`/`lambda`. Функции написанные в коде тела класса называются методами и представляют собой функции оборачиваемые на лету в дополнительный объект типа `Method` (условное название). Принадлежат они объекту класса, а не его экземплярам.

Объект-обёртка позволяет при вызове метода неявно передавать первым аргументом объект у которого этот метод вызывается: `self`, `cls`. В случае обычного метода это сам экземпляр, обычно называемый `self` в сигнатуре метода, в случае `classmethod` поведение меняется декоратором `@classmethod` и первым аргументом передаётся объект класса, который принято называть `cls`. `staticmethod` сделан так, чтобы при обращении к методу, возвращалась сама функция, без оборачивания в объект типа `Method`.

Код функций написанных в юзерском классе на этапе компиляции превращается в **code objects**, затем на этапе исполнения отрабатывают конструкции `def` внутри класса и создаются **function objects** - заготовки под методы. Ссылками на эти function objects владеет объект-класс и добраться до них можно через его атрибуты, **CPython** хранит function objects в сегменте **heap**, как и все остальные объекты исполняемой программы. Одна функция внутри тела класса соответствует одному объекту в heap'е. Экземпляры же получают доступ к этому объекту через класс родитель. **И для 100, и для 1000 экземпляров будет 1 function object в heap'e.**

**Пример:**

Конструкция `class MyClass` в коде ведёт к созданию объекта `MyClass`. Имена в теле класса `MyClass` становятся его атрибутами. При создании экземпляра `obj = MyClass()` новому объекту `obj` записывается ссылка на `MyClass`. При вызове у `obj` метода - `obj.class_body_method(some_arg)`, происходит приблизительно следующее:

- поиск атрибута `class_body_method` в определённом порядке - у самого экземпляра `obj`, в цепочке mro его родителя - `MyClass`, в метаклассе - типе от которого происходит `MyClass` (обычно это `type`). В экземпляре ссылка на метод может храниться только если он был целенаправленно сохранён в качестве атрибута экземпляра.
- так как методы класса реализованы при помощи **descriptor protocol**, после нахождении атрибута/дескриптора `class_body_method`,  у него вызывается метод `__get__`, в котором происходят манипуляции, необходимые для превращения функции в метод определённого типа. В связи с тем, что превращение функции в обычный метод происходит при каждом обращении, **id'шники вновь создаваемого метод-объекта будут разные**, но не для `staticmethod`, так как там оборачивания не происходит и возвращается сама функция, каждый раз один и тот же объект, соответственно и **id'шник не меняется**.

**Демонстрация различных моментов упомянутых в предыдущем тексте**

```
class MyClass:
    def class_body_method_1(self):
        pass

    def class_body_method_2(self, arg2, some_arg=[]):
        some_arg.append(arg2)   
        print(some_arg)

    @staticmethod
    def class_body_staticmethod():
        pass

obj1 = MyClass()
obj2 = MyClass()
obj3 = MyClass()
```

Смена id'шника при каждом обращении к обычному методу:

```
In []: id(obj1.class_body_method_1)
Out[]: 140714545102720

In []: id(obj1.class_body_method_1)
Out[]: 140714546939712
```

Но не в случае @staticmethod:

```
In []: id(obj1.class_body_staticmethod)
Out[]: 140714331142272

In []: id(obj1.class_body_staticmethod)
Out[]: 140714331142272
```

Потому что при обращении к обычному методу каждый раз заново создаётся и возвращается объект-метод:

```
In []: obj1.class_body_method_1
Out[]: <bound method MyClass.class_body_method_1 of <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7ffaa8a0c790>>
```

Имеющий ссылку на один и тот же объект-функцию:

```
In []: obj1.class_body_method_1.__func__
Out[]: <function __main__.MyClass.class_body_method_1(self)>

In []: id(obj1.class_body_method_1.__func__)
Out[]: 140714331143568

In []: id(obj1.class_body_method_1.__func__)
Out[]: 140714331143568
```

А staticmethod просто возвращает саму функцию:

```
In []: obj1.class_body_staticmethod
Out[]: <function __main__.MyClass.class_body_staticmethod()>
```

Следствием и доказательством одного функции-объекта для всех экземпляров являются, например, такие вещи (один дефолтный массив на всех):

```
In []: obj1.class_body_method_2("a")
['a']

In []: obj1.class_body_method_2("b")
['a', 'b']

In []: obj2.class_body_method_2("c")
['a', 'b', 'c']

In []: obj3.class_body_method_2("d")
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё поразмыслив, я всё же склонился к тому, что код методов экземпляров класса размещается в памяти динамически:
Во-первых, методы **init** и **del** совершенно бессмысленно хранить в памяти для каждого экземпляра: они выполняются всего один раз (а синтаксически - это однозначно методы экземпляра класса).
Во-вторых, в любой момент к существующим методам экземпляров класса можно добавить новый:

```
    def newmethod(self):
        pass
    Myclass.meth99=newmethod
```

Если бы у каждого уже существующего экземпляра класса присутствовала в памяти программы копия кода всех методов экземпляра класса, то добавление нового метода было бы довольно сложной и затратной задачей.